# Degree of Kinematic Indeterminacy

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering

Is the degree of indeterminacy 3 in this structure?
How to clearly determine DOKI of a structure?
I am confused to determine whether hinge D can allow rotation to occur in this diagram.
Rotation: at B/ (Is D also counted as rotation?)
Displacement: Vertical direction in D

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The structure is statically indeterminate to the third degree (1+2+3 = 6 unknowns - 3 equations).

The degree of kinematic indeterminacy equals the number of freedom of the joints. For your case, use the guide table below, and assume the axial strain of members are negligible, you should find the kinematic indeterminacy equals the structural indeterminacy - "3".

[image][image]

[Ref](https://testbook.com/objective-questions/mcq-on-kinematic-indeterminacy--5eea6a0839140f30f369d823#:%7E:text=Kinematic%20indeterminacy%20%28D%20K%29%20also%20known%20as%20degree,the%20degree%20of%20freedom.%20NOTE%3A%20Neglecting%20axial%20strain.)

Comment: How about DOKI? Is it also 3?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But may i confirm where will the rotation and displacement occur? since the DOKI is 3. I only know one is from rotation of joint B and the other is displacement at joint D.

Comment: Total degree of freedom (KI) = 1(A)+3(B)+2(C)+1(D) = 7. Ignore axial effect, the final KI = 7-4 = 3. The degree of freedom is listed on the table enclosed in the answer.